# Triggers override binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why is it that the binding `Marked` stops working when the triggers are used? Is there some way to fix this?

The multi selection `ListBox` has `ListBoxItem`s with `CheckBox`es, and the checkbox in an item is ticked when the corresponding item is selected, using mouse or keyboard or touch or whatever. The point with this demo is to not tick the checkboxes directly, but just multiselect the items and see the checkboxes get ticked as a consequence of that. This synchronization in the XAML works well, but since the `Marked` binding isn't working, the model won't get updated.

If I remove the triggers, then the binding `Marked` starts working. I know, because then the model gets updated when the checkboxes are ticked.

If I attach event handlers for `Checked` and `Unchecked` to the `CheckBox`, they fire even when the triggers are there.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cb"
                        Content="{Binding DisplayText}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Marked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="cb" Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="cb" Property="IsChecked" Value="false"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

EDIT:
Although the accepted solution below is good XAML, it crashes with Elmish.WPF, which I'm using. That's another issue, and will be solved through other forums.

Comment: How do you expect this to be fixed? It's just contradictory. Use either the Binding or the DataTriggers (which seems to make no sense anyway).

Comment: You probably just want to bind the ListBoxItems' IsSelected property to the Marked property in an ItemContainerStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTriggers will obviously override the Binding, since the ListBoxItem's `IsSelected` property is always either `true` or `false`.

Replace the DataTriggers by an ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding DisplayText}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Marked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Marked}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I don't think you're answering the "why" part of the question. Why would a template trigger override a Binding when it's supposed to [have lower precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)?

Comment: @CorentinPane Property value precedence would apply if there would be a Style or Template for a CheckBox.

Comment: I replaced CheckBox with Label, and only kept the DisplayText binding there. Still didn't work. Then I removed ListBox.ItemContainerStyle, and then DisplayText worked. Also, when selecting an item with the ItemContainerStyle in place, there was an exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: @BentTranberg Not sure what you are doing there, but the solution presented here works fine, provided there is a Marked property with change notification in the element type of the Lines collection.

Comment: I'm at a point now where I suspect the problem is not in my source, but in the Elmish.WPF framework that I'm using. I will create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @Clemens yes right. But you're still not answering the why!

Comment: You mean why I wrote that complicated XAML? I didn't know I couldn't have both. It was part of debugging what was going on. I've tried all sorts of ways throughout the day, and keep getting that same exception with various techniques. I'll post a link to the issue when it's ready, and I'll throw in a link to my repo there too.

Comment: @CorentinPane Why? Because value precedence doesn't matter.

Comment: I'd like you to justify the assertion "The DataTriggers will obviously override the Binding". Why does a Setter applied value override a Binding? Why doesn't it simply trigger an update of the two way Binding?

Comment: @Clemens, I finally solved my original issue, which was caused by a silly editing mistake in my source that compiled and went unnoticed. Once that was found, it worked perfectly with your solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And the final result is here: https://github.com/BentTranberg/ElmiDemos and it's MultiSel2 that reflects your solution.